# How do I get customer group name using Bigcommerce API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a user list and I want to show Customer Group Name with each customer. 
I used:

`$customers = Bigcommerce::getCustomers();`

To retrieve customer information.

The above function returns customer group id; can anyone help me telling how can I get customer group name?

I am very new to Bigcommerce API -  any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the PHP Library found here:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

Use this to print full information on all your customers:

```
$customers = Bigcommerce::getCustomers();
foreach($customers as $customer) {
    print_r(Bigcommerce::getCustomer($customer->id));
}
```

You will notice however, that within the list returned, it only gives a customer group ID. To get the associated name with a customer group id, you would have to run:

```
$group_name = Bigcommerce::getResource('/customer_groups/' ."$GROUP_ID");
//Where $GROUP_ID is the ID gotten from the first snippet.
```

Here's a little example which prints the first name, last name, and email of a customer, as well as the name of its associated customer group:

```
$echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
$customers = Bigcommerce::getCustomers();
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    echo "Customer Info: \n";
    echo "First Name: $customer->first_name \n";
    echo "Last Name: $customer->last_name \n";
    echo "eMail: $customer->email \n";

    $customer_group = Bigcommerce::getResource('/customer_groups/' ."$customer->customer_group_id");
    echo "Customer Group: $customer_group->name \n";
    echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
}
```

Should output something similar to:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Customer Info: 
First Name: John 
Last Name: Doe 
eMail: JohnDoe@bigcommerce.com
Customer Group: Retail
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Please reference the following URL for more information on the objects returned for $customer:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/customers

Answer (score 0):

PHP code to get the Customer Group whose Group ID is equal to 1:

```
$customer_group = Bigcommerce::getResource('/customer_groups/' ."1");  
echo "Customer ID: $customer_group->id \n";
echo "<br>";
echo "Customer Group Name: $customer_group->name \n";
echo "<br>";`enter code here`
```

## Results

Customer ID: 1

## Customer Group Name: GSA